# I need the type of an property with there value to make validation easyer

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need help with typescript typings. I want a type that has the same keys and a function that has the key value type included :).

Maybe someone can help me out, i add this example here what i want to achieve

```
export const useFormValidation = <T>(state: T, validator: Validator<T>) => {
  console.log(state, validator);
};
```

validation should be something like this if

```
type Person {
  name: string;
  active: boolean;
  hobbies?: Array<string>;
}
```

generated type for Validator should be like this if i use the function

useFormValidation({name: 'michi', active: true}, **the needed type**)

type -> should be

```
{ 
  name: (value: string) => boolean,
  active: (value: boolean) => boolean,
  hobbies: (value: Array<string>) => boolean,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me out

```
export type Validator<T> = (value: T) => Promise<boolean> | boolean;

export type Validation<T extends { [key: string]: any }, K extends keyof Required<T>> = {
  [P in K]: Validator<T[P]>;
};

export const useFormValidation = <T>(state: Required<T>, validator: Validation<T, keyof T>) => {
   ---implementation---
};
```